# Returning specific value of javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a script which returns this as "r2":

```
{
    waitSeconds: 0,
    runSeconds: 0,
    report: {
        data: [{
            breakdown: [{}],
            breakdownTotal: ["608674"],
            day: 1,
            month: 10,
            name: "Mon.  1 Oct. 2018",
            year: 2018,
        }, {
            name: "Tue.  2 Oct. 2018",
            year: 2018,
            month: 10,
            day: 2,
            breakdown: [{}],
            breakdownTotal: ["123456"]
        }, {
            name: "Wed.  3 Oct. 2018",
            year: 2018,
            month: 10,
            day: 3,
            breakdown: [{}],
            breakdownTotal: ["123456"]
        }, {
            name: "Thu.  4 Oct. 2018",
            year: 2018,
            month: 10,
            day: 4,
            breakdown: [{}],
            breakdownTotal: ["123456"]
        }, ],
        elements: [{}],
        metrics: [{}],
    }
}
```

I'm trying to capture two things and return them in the format:

```
[X,Y,Z,ETC]
```

I've been able to grab the day using this code:

```
const days = r2.report.data.map(obj => obj.day);
```

However when I try and get breakdownTotal (i.e 608674)

```
const metric = r2.report.data.map(obj => obj.breakdownTotal);
```

It returns this:

```
[Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
```

How can I get it to return the breakdownTotal values?

Comment: `breakdownTotal` is an array in your example data, so that seems correct. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: But you are getting the value, the code you've posted above says that `breakdownTotal` is an array, you can do `const metric = r2.report.data.map(obj => obj.breakdownTotal[0]);` to get them to be `"608674"` but that's assuming the value of `breakdownTotal` always only has one value in the array, or do you just want the value of const to be `"608674"`?

Comment: @Jerodev I'm trying to get the number. of breakdown total (608674)

Comment: It is an array, try this to fetch first index `r2.report.data.map(obj => obj.breakdownTotal[0]);`

Comment: @Jimmy in Chrome's console, you can use the expression: `copy(r2)` to copy the variable as formatted JSON into your clipboard. Otherwise you can log `JSON.stringify(r2, null, 2)` and then manually copy the output. This helps people understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You want the first value of the breakdown array not the array itself, right?

```
const metric = r2.report.data.map(obj => obj.breakdownTotal[0]);
```

Try this?